# Select all rows for which there are at least 30 instaces of an id within an association table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have an association table, PostToTag containing only 2 columns, post_id and tag_id. I would like to filter out every row containing a tag_id for which there are fewer than 30 instances of that tag_id in the PostToTag table.

```
SELECT ptt.post_id, ptt.tag_id, COUNT(tag_id) n FROM PostToTag ptt GROUP BY tag_id HAVING n >= 30
```

The code above is close to what I need, but I'd like to get all tag_ids as if I hadn't used a GROUP BY. I'm used to working with dplyr in R, and being able to ungroup after executing aggregate functions. What is the conventional way to 'ungroup' in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . use window functions:

```
SELECT ptt.*
FROM (SELECT ptt.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ptt.tag_id) as cnt
      FROM PostToTag ptt 
     ) ptt
WHERE cnt >= 30;
```